# How to pass new options with cheerio with a loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im tryin to call goforit() function with new options each time the function is finished.
I just want to modify the value of actualpage pass it to baseuri.

Can you help ? I turn around like a fish

actually the function return the same options, but the value actualpage is changing

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var cookiejar = rp.jar();
var actualpage = 1;
var baseuri = 'https://www.website.page=' + actualpage;
var options = {
  uri: baseuri,
  headers: {
    'Host': 'www.website.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  },
  jar: cookiejar,
  transform: function(body) {
    return cheerio.load(body);
  }
};

goforit()

function goforit() {
  actualpage = actualpage + 1
  baseuri = 'https://www.website.com' + actualpage;

  setTimeout(function() {
    rp(options)
      .then(($) => {
        var arr = 0
        arr = $('.bt__media__content p')

        var fruits = $('.bt__ment p');
        fruits.each(function(i, elem) {
          console.log(fruits[i].children[0].attribs)
        });
        goforit()

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using latest node version.

`options = {...options, uri: baseuri}`

**options can be updated by using spread operator.**

add this line,

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var cookiejar = rp.jar();
var actualpage = 1;
var baseuri = 'https://www.website.page=' + actualpage;
var options = {
  uri: baseuri,
  headers: {
    'Host': 'www.website.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  },
  jar: cookiejar,
  transform: function(body) {
    return cheerio.load(body);
  }
};

goforit()

function goforit() {
  actualpage = actualpage + 1
  baseuri = 'https://www.website.com' + actualpage;
  // add this line 
  options = {...options, uri: baseuri}
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    rp(options)
      .then(($) => {
        var arr = 0
        arr = $('.bt__media__content p')

        var fruits = $('.bt__ment p');
        fruits.each(function(i, elem) {
          console.log(fruits[i].children[0].attribs)
        });
        goforit()

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Yes I found this solution few minutes ago, too late ;) but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

you have to increment the value of  (actualpage) before function end like this

```
function goforit() {
    actualpage = actualpage + 1
    baseuri = 'https://www.website.com' + actualpage;

   setTimeout(function() {
       rp(options).then(($) => {
        var arr = 0
        arr = $('.bt__media__content p')
        var fruits = $('.bt__ment p');
        fruits.each(function(i, elem) {
        console.log(fruits[i].children[0].attribs)
    });
    actualpage++;
    goforit()

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 }, 3000);
}
```

so when your function is call (  actualpage  ) is incremente.

hope it helps..